# Return input type of generic with type constraint in LINQ to Entities (EF4.1)

Tags: c#, linq, generics, linq-to-entities

I have a simple extension method for filtering a LINQ IQueryable by tags. I'm using this with LINQ to Entities with an interface of:

```
public interface ITaggable
{
    ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; } 
}
```

The following does not work, returning `IQueryable<ITaggable>` instead of `IQueryable<T>`:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereTagged<T>(this IQueryable<T> set, string tag) where T:ITaggable
    {
        return set.Where(s=>s.Tags.Any(t=>t.Name.ToLower() == tag.ToLower()));
    }
```

This leads to a LINQ to Entities cast exception:

> "Unable to cast the type 'ReleaseGateway.Models.Product' to type
>   'ReleaseGateway.Models.ITaggable'. LINQ to Entities only supports
>   casting Entity Data Model primitive types."
>   (System.NotSupportedException) A System.NotSupportedException was
>   caught: "Unable to cast the type 'Project.Models.Product' to type
>   'Project.Models.ITaggable'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting
>   Entity Data Model primitive types."

It works without the constraint like this, but I have to explicitly declare the type T in my application code:

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereTagged<T>(this IQueryable<ITaggable> set, string tag)
{
    return set.Where(s=>s.Tags.Any(t=>t.Name.ToLower() == tag.ToLower())).Cast<T>();
}
```

**Question:** Why does the type constraint cast the return type? Can I rewrite this to take advantage of inferring the type from the extension method caller?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: You're right, on the first example the .Cast<T> is redundant. I'll edit that. But the exception is the same. I think it's related specifically to LINQ to Entities.

Comment: What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: I'm using EF 4.1, Code First.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking for the same answer and not being satisfied with the syntactic cleanliness of the answers provided, I kept looking and found this post.

tl;dr; - **add class to your constraints and it works**.

[LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types with IEntity interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976495/linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-edm-primitive-or-enumeration-types-with-i)

```
public static IQueryable<T> WhereTagged<T>(this IQueryable<T> set, string tag)
    where T: class, ITaggable
```

Answer (score 7):

I suspect that the problem arises from the call to `s.Tags`. Because `s` is a `Product`, but you're calling `ITaggable.Tags`, the expression that gets generated looks more like:

```
set.Where(s=>((ITaggable)s).Tags.Any(...))
```

That just confuses Entity Framework. Try this:

```
((IQueryable<ITaggable>)set)
    .Where(s=>s.Tags.Any(t=>t.Name.ToLower() == tag.ToLower()))
    .Cast<T>();
```

Since `IQueryable` is a covariant interface, this will treat the set as an `IQueryable<ITaggable>`, which should work since your second example basically does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Thanks - that works! Might want to edit this answer for others' reference.

Comment: @JasonDenizac: Does that look better?

Comment: Yes - again, I appreciate the help.

Comment: Thank you so much!  That's just saved me from a big headache! :-)

Comment: Thanks man, very simple and clever. I wasted almost a day for a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You never show where this is used. I think you are already passing an `IQueryable<ITaggable>` to the method in the first place.

Proof of concept https://ideone.com/W8c66

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public interface ITaggable {}

    public struct TagStruct : ITaggable {}
    public class  TagObject : ITaggable {}

    public static IEnumerable<T> DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) 
        where T: ITaggable
    {
        foreach (var i in input) yield return i;
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var structs = new [] { new TagStruct() };
        var objects = new [] { new TagObject() };

        Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(structs).First().GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(DoSomething(objects).First().GetType());               
    }
}
```

Output

```
Program+TagStruct
Program+TagObject
```

So, it is returning the input type, not the constrained interface.

Not surprising, what would have been the result if DoSometing required two interfaces?

```
    public static IEnumerable<T> DoSomething<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) 
        where T: ITaggable, ISerializable
```

??

Comment: This is used on, for example, db.Products.WhereTagged("NonQuarterlyRelease") where db is a DbContext and Products is a DbSet<Product>

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will find that `WhereTagged` return `IQueryable<ITaggable>`...

Comment: Yep. It works great with LINQ to Objects, but breaks in LINQ to Entities.

Comment: I see. Sorry, that's outside my jurisdiction than. I'd be most interested if it worked differently. I'm guessing it shouldn't. Regardless, most curious

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that Cast at the end as dlev mentioned.

I assume the product class implements ITaggable? I think removing the Cast will fix the problem.

Comment: The cast was redundant, I've edited it out. I still receive the same exception, however.