# How to use interface from entity framework database first auto-generated code

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following two classes auto generated with Entity Framework using database first;

```
public partial class UserXml
{
    public UserXml()
    {
        this.UserXmlHotel = new HashSet<UserXmlHotel>();
    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public byte FailedAttempt { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual UserXmlIp UserXmlIp { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<UserXmlHotel> UserXmlHotel { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public partial class UserCustomer 
{
    public UserCustomer ()
    {
        this.UserCustomerHotel = new HashSet<UserCustomerHotel >();
    }

    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public bool Enabled { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I've then created the following classes;

```
public partial class UserXml : IUser
{
}

public partial class UserCustomer : IUser
{
}

public static class EntityExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> Enabled<T>(this IQueryable<T> source) where T : IUser
    {
        return source.Where(x => x.Enabled);
    }
}
```

I have a interface as;

```
public interface IUser
{
    bool Enabled { get; }
}
```

Want I'm wanting to do is combine the same call for each entity using the same re-usable code; So take

```
using(var Context = new EscapeEntities())
{
     bool bEnabled = Context.UserXml.First(u => u.UserId == iUserId).Enabled;
}
```

and

```
using(var Context = new EscapeEntities())
{
     bool bEnabled = Context.UserCustomer.First(u => u.UserId == iUserId).Enabled;
}
```

I'm wanting to use my EntityExtensions class, but I'm having trouble getting it to work.  Any pointers ?

Comment: Do you have compile errors or the query doesn't get what you want ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use expressions on generic types which implement an interface, the expression builder adds a cast to the expression, like below:

```
x => x.Enabled // converts to something like below: 
x => ((IUser)x).Enabled
```

So what you need to do is to tell the expression builder to not add the cast expression by defining your generic type as a class, which means your `Enabled(...)` extension method needs to be like this:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Enabled<T>(this IQueryable<T> source) 
  where T : class, IUser // added 'class' constraint
{
    return source.Where(x => x.Enabled);
}
```

Another approach (which needs much more work) is to define an `ExpressionVisitor` class to remove the convert on the expression which is explained on this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18976497/1126168).

So after this correction, you can user your extension method easily:

```
using(var Context = new EscapeEntities())
{
    IQueryable<UserXml> query = Context.UserXml
        .Where(u => u.Password == "Foo")).Enabled();
    List<UserXml> res = query.ToList();
}
```

**P.S.** I think you'd be better off with defining another extra "base" `User` table with two children named `UserXml` and `UserCustomer` and abstract out the common columns into `User` table, which removes the need for extra interfaces and is also compatible with object oriented design.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you have sample for adding a bas class as per your recommendation

Comment: It seems there's no such question on stackoverflow, so I decided to ask this question. Look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22263190/1126168).