# Entity Framework DB-First, implement inheritance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, ef-database-first

I'm trying to implement inheritance using entity framework 6.0 and database first approach. OK, let's say I have a `Person` and an `Organization` entity like below:

```cs
// a simplified version of organization entity
public class Organization
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public string OfficialName { get; set; }
    public Guid CEOID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? RegisterDate { get; set; }
}

// a simplified version of person entity
public class Person
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    public Guid PersonID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string NationalCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
}
```

I can create these two tables in database, but I want to use inheritance so the fields which is repeated in both `Person` and `Organization` could be in another base class like below:

```cs
public class Identity
{
    // These fields are the common fields between Person and Organization
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Nickname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
}
```

How can I achieve this in db-first approach?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One possible way is to use **one table** for **each type** called **TPT** (table-per-type), which I prefer to use. To achieve this, you define your tables like the model shown in the following picture:

[image: table hierarchy]

Note that the relationships between child and base entity are **one-to-one** on their pk columns, and all common fields are moved to the base table. After creating your tables, right click on the models page in your visual studio, and select **Update Model from Database...**, and then in the add tab, select these 3 tables to add. At first you should see this model diagram, which needs to be changed a bit:

[image: tables added at first]

Do these steps for `Person` and `Organization` separately:

- Right click on entity and select **Properties**
- In the **Base Type** property select `Identity`
- Select and then **delete the association** between this entity and `Identity`
- Select and then **Delete the PK** (ID column) of this entity (Inherits from base entity)

After these steps save your model. Now your model should look like this:

[image: the changed model]

Now compile your project and enjoy your life!

Additional resources:
[Entity Framework Designer TPH Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj618292(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: TPH just means 1 table per base class and some masking to only select columns related to the base and subclass properties of a specific class. There's a lot less joins, but a bunch of sparsely populated columns.

Comment: I get an error about my foreign key from the child table to the PK in the parent table. `Insufficient mapping: Foreign key must be mapped to some AssociationSet or EntitySets participating in a foreign key association on the conceptual side.` I believe we deleted that in your 3rd bullet step. Any ideas? Does it really need to be deleted? The error goes away if I don't delete it, but I'm not sure if it actually works at runtime yet.

Comment: If I remove the association I get the error "An Association or inheritance relationship needs to be created to enforce this constraint.(...).
Keeping the one-to-one association worked perfectly for me! Thanks