# Entity Framework DB First - Problems with inheritance in the model

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, db-first

I'm facing some problems working with EF DB First. Say I've got:

- A table Person
- A table Student with a foreign key pointing to Person
- A table Teacher with a foreign key pointing to Person

[image: DB structure]

The model created from the database generates the next classes:

```
public class Person{
  this.Student= new HashSet<Student>();
  this.Teacher= new HashSet<Teacher>(); 
}

public class Student{}
public class Teacher{}
```

And what I'd really like to see is

```
public class Person{}
public class Student:Person{}
public class Teacher:Person{}
```

Is there any convention over configuration or anything I'm missing to get the inherited classes ?

**UPDATE**

Classes are generated in such a way because the model specifies these associations between Person, Teacher and Student. My question should be then...*Is there any way to create a model from a DB using EF so that the model contains classes that inherit from other ones?*

Comment: show us the structure of your tables

Comment: What do you mean DB First? If you do use a model, you can change the inheritance mapping there and the generated classes will be updated. If you reverse-engineered a database in a Code First project, you'll have to make the changes to mappings and classes by hand. EF can't guess whether the relation implies inheritance

Comment: I've described in more detail what the problem is. As @PanagiotisKanavos says, it's not an automated process

Comment: @jobmo - *the programmer* modifies the model after reverse engineering. The classes will be regenerated after that. The model builder has no way of guessing whether a foreign key should be mapped as inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for Table-per-Type (TPT) mapping. Try the solution here:

[Entity Framework DB-First, implement inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263189/entity-framework-db-first-implement-inheritance)