# Entity Framework DB First and 'override' keyword

Tags: c#, entity-framework, overriding, partial-classes

Suppose I have the class

```
public class Parent {
    virtual string Name {get; set;}
}

public partial class Child : Parent {
}
```

When I use EF DB first, it generates the following:

```
public partial class Child {
    string Name {get; set;}
}
```

How do I get it to use the '`override`' keyword for Name? I don't want to add that every time I update the DB.

Comment: Use code first from database, designer from database leaves you with little to no flexibility

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create you model using inheritance check those links:

[Entity Framework DB-First, implement inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263189/entity-framework-db-first-implement-inheritance)

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

if you want to create new properties that is not in your db to an existing class in your model, try use partial classes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/wa80x488.aspx