# How to prevent EF6 to merge entities when using database first?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three tables: user, specialUser and special

User contains all the base fields. specialUser has an id which is both, the FK (to user table) and PK and has another field specialId, which is a FK to the special table.

Now, when I add the tables to the edmx, EF has merged the specialuser with the user entity! User now has an extra navigation property to special. I don't want this. I want to have a separate entity for specialuser.

How can I force EF 6 not to merge these entities?

Comment: How are these entities related?  Do they have an inheritance relationship?

Comment: That is what I want to achieve. User as the base and specialuser as the child

Comment: Okay, it's doing "Table Per Hierarchy".  You need/want "Table Per Type" or "Table Per Concrete Class".  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22263189/entity-framework-db-first-implement-inheritance

Comment: Thanks, i also found that question, but my problem is that in his case Identity is merged with Person (i don't have additional properties for now in my child entity)

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue in the past, the only way I got the result I wanted is adding an extra column to the table, like EF_FIX bit nullable to the table.

add something like this to **specialUser** and it should do, i think, what you want