# Refactoring two methods to use interface and/or generics

Tags: c#, generics, interface, refactoring

I have a program that passes some query criteria, for multiple types of class, that is used by EF to query data back from a db. There is a criteria class for each type that is being queried, but there is a lot of duplication and similarity between these methods which I'd hoped to refactor out, but without success.

These are example (simplified) service methods:

```
private static IQueryable<Class1> FilterClass1ResultsOnId(Class1QueryCriteria queryCriteria, IQueryable<Class1> queryResults)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryCriteria.Id))
        {
            queryResults = from view in queryResults where view.Id==queryCriteria.Id select view;
        }
        return queryResults;
    }


private static IQueryable<Class2> FilterClass2ResultsOnId(Class2QueryCriteria queryCriteria, IQueryable<Class2> queryResults)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryCriteria.Id))
        {
            queryResults = from view in queryResults where view.Id == queryCriteria.Id select view;
        }
        return queryResults;
    }
```

... which are called like this ...

```
queryResults = FilterClass1ResultsOnId(queryCriteria, queryResults);
```

The service has a series of these 'FilterClassXonSOMECRITERIA' methods to narrow down the IQueryable that is ultimately returned. There are a lot of these service methods that are essentially identical apart from the type of the input parameters and the type of the output.

I initially tried to refactor the methods to accept a `queryResults` argument that was an interface rather than a concrete class - a simple interface that just has an `Id` property - and then made `Class1` and `Class2` implement that interface. But then I need to make the return type of these methods non-concrete too if I want to use just the one method. This is where I got stuck.

I have been looking around and have seen **covariance** and **contravariance** information, but I can't seem to define a method/interface that uses these interfaces and a generic type without getting 'cannot resolve symbol T' or 'Argument type XXX is not assignable to parameter type YYY''.

At this point I wanted to sanity check with those more familiar with this problem: Is what I am trying to do possible? Can I have methods that take an argument specified only by interface, and return from that method an object also only specified by an interface?

EDIT: the criteria classes are pretty straightforward, and are actually complex types defined in the EF model. But here's a simplified example:

```
public class Class1QueryCriteria
{
  public string Id;
  public string Name;
}

public class Class2QueryCriteria
{
  public string Id;
  public string Category;
}
```

Comment: Will your post a sample code of `Class1QueryCriteria ` and `Class2QueryCriteria`?

Comment: See edit, but they are simple data classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to define an interface for the criteria:

```
interface IQueryCriteria {
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

..and, if necessary, an interface for your "view" types:

```
interface IViewType {
    string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then your method (non-plural) can be generic:

```
private static IQueryable<T> FilterClassResultsOnId<T>(IQueryCriteria queryCriteria, IQueryable<T> queryResults) 
    where T : IViewType
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryCriteria.Id))
    {
        queryResults = from view in queryResults where view.Id == queryCriteria.Id select view;
    }
    return queryResults;
}
```

The key here is the generic type constraint `where T : IViewType`. This allows the use of `view.Id` in the body of the method, because the compiler can confirm that the type will at least implement the interface with the `Id` property.

Comment: Perfect. The bit I was missing was the `where T : IViewType` (and also the `<T>` after the method name). I then ran into the kind of problem talked about here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976495/entity-framework-linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-edm-primitive-or-enumer so had to make the change to `where T : class, IViewType`.

Answer (score 2):

You can build the filter expression manually:

```
private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> WhereById<T>(string id)
{
    var pExpr = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var idExpr = Expression.Property(pExpr, "Id");
    var eqExpr = Expression.Equal(idExpr, Expression.Constant(id));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(eqExpr, pExpr);
}

private static IQueryable<T> FilterById<T>(string id, IQueryable<T> source)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(queryCriteria.Id))
    {
        var whereExpr = WhereById<T>(string id);
        return source.Where(whereExpr);
    }
    return queryResults;
}

private static IQueryable<Class1> FilterClass1ResultsOnId(Class1QueryCriteria queryCriteria, IQueryable<Class1> queryResults)
{
    return FilterById(queryCriteria.Id, queryResults);
}
```

You can avoid the need for separate overloads if you create an base type with the string `Id` property.

Alternatively you could make the criteria class generic and include the query expression directly e.g.

```
public class QueryCriteria<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> FilterExpression { get; set; }
}
```

then you could write something like:

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterResults<T>(QueryCriteria<T> criteria, IQueryable<T> source)
{
    return criteria.FilterExpression == null ? source : source.Where(criteria.FilterExpression);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, and for the info on building expressions manually. I've toyed with this before, but then favour readability over `Expression<Func<T,Bool>>`! My example methods were also simplified, as the real filter methods have a bit more logic in them - something I don't look forward to converting into an expression tree. One day, when I'm feeling brave, I'll come back and dive into expression trees with both feet.