# Unable to cast to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey'

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I tried to cast an collection of entities to a collection of IEntityWithKey but I got this exception:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'Models.Person' to
>   type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey'.
>   LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration
>   types.

The code is

```
var entities = somePersons

IQueryable<Person> personsQuery = query
IEnumerable<IEntityWithKey> entityKeyList = entities

personsQuery.Where(a => entityKeyList.Contains(a))
```

Purpose of the query is to match against the EntityKey.

What's LINQ to Entities complaining about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types with IEntity interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976495/linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-edm-primitive-or-enumeration-types-with-i)

Comment: It might be more helpful to others if you include the assignments of `personsQuery` and `entityKeyList` in your code sample.