# How to create an AS expression in Expression tree builder

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, expression

How do we create an AS expression in Expression tree builder?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#as-operator

We have an Iqueryable, we want to check a property of the object.
By doing so we use `Expression.Convert` to convert the parameterexpression to a class.
Afterwards we get an error we try to run this query on the DbContext:
*'Unable to cast the type 'System.Object' to type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Ourclass'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.'*

Code we use:

```cs
        Expression<Func<object, bool>> Example<T>(T customeType)
        {
            ParameterExpression e = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
            var converted =  Expression.Convert(e, customeType.GetType());
            MemberExpression u = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(converted, "IsDeleted");           
            BinaryExpression isDeleted = Expression.Equal(u, Expression.Constant(false));
            Expression<Func<object, bool>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(isDeleted, e);
            return lambda;
        }
```

The above code compiles to something like: `m => ((OurClass)m).IsDeleted == false`.
However this is not valid code for Linq to Entities.
We want something like `m => (m as OurClass).IsDeleted == false`.
Is it possible to generate a dynamic expression?
We do not want to use ToList for performance reasons.

Answer (score 2):

The equivalent of:

```
(OurClass)x
```

is:

```
Expression.Convert(x, typeof(Ourclass));
```

The equivalent of:

```
x as OurClass
```

is:

```
Expression.TypeAs(x, typeof(OurClass));
```

Note that you should always check the result of an `as` cast to see whether the cast failed and the result is `null`.

---

An easy way to investigate expressions is to get the compiler to construct them. For your case, I wrote:

```
Expression<Func<object, string>> foo = x => x as string;
```

You can then either look at `foo` in a debugger, or put that into [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0ATEBqAPgAQCYBGAWACh8AGAAn2IDoAZASwDsBHAbgursdacGAUQQAHWAGdJLCG0k9KAZjqEaAYRoBvCjT10V+FDQCyACgCU23ftuiJMabLYAefAFYXEYACsYYABc0fioAPlCaADMICBoAXhoEeIikgENJEMVbAF8KbKA==) and see what the compiler generates.

Comment: Hello @canton7 thanks for the answer. After using TypeAs we get the error: "input of type 'System.Object' and a check of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.OurClass' is not supported. Only entity types and complex types are supported in LINQ to Entities queries.'" when we use ToList().

Comment: @Jesper1 Indeed. I answered your question, but I think you asked the wrong question -- the question is how you do casting of any type with EF, not how to do s specific sort of cast. Perhaps look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976495/linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-edm-primitive-or-enumeration-types-with-i)?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to wrap your `as` expression in a method:

```
public static TResult As<T, TResult>(T obj)
    where TResult : class
{
    return obj as TResult;
}
```

Then use a `MethodCallExpression` to activate it.