# Checking property of derived entity type using EF6?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a `IQueryable<BaseEntity>` and there are derived entities `EntityA` and `EntityB`. I want my query to return ALL `EntityA` objects and only those `EntityB` objects which have a certain property not set to a certain value.

Unfortunately, the following code:

```
IQueryable<BaseEntity> baseEntities = GetBaseEntities();
var result = baseEntities.Where(x => !(x is EntityB) || ((EntityB) x).Prop != MyConstants.Value).ToList();
```

Throws an error:

> NotSupportedException: Unable to cast the type 'BaseEntity' to type 'EntityB'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

How to overcome this problem?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976495/linq-to-entities-only-supports-casting-edm-primitive-or-enumeration-types-with-i

Comment: I don't see where I could put the "where T :  class" modifier, I don't have any generics in my code..

Answer (score 0):

One workaround seems to be the following:

```
GetAllEntityA().Cast<BaseEntity>().Concat(GetAllEntityB(b => b.Prop != MyConstants.Value))
```

I'm still looking for a better answer though.