# LinqToEntities Generic Classes and Interface

Tags: c#, generics, linq-to-entities

```
public class CoreEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //some additional common fields like insertedBy, insertedAt etc
}
public interface IUniqueObject
{
    Guid Uid { get; set; }
}
public class Tag : CoreEntity
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}

public class ItemTags : CoreEntity
{
    public Guid TaggedItemUid { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
}


public class Repository<T>
    where T : CoreEntity
{
    public DbSet<T> TheEntitySet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ItemTags> ItemTagSet { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<T> AddTagsFilter(IQueryable<T> query, List<int> tags)
    {
        var ts = ItemTagSet;
        if (typeof (T) is IUniqueObject)
        {
            query = query.Where(f => ts.Any(e => e.TaggedItemUid == ((IUniqueObject)f).Uid && tags.Contains(e.TagId));
        }
        return query;
    }
}

//usage
public class Departman : CoreEntity, IUniqueObject
{
    public Guid Uid { get; set; }
    //some other fields
}
class Test
{

    void xx()
    {
        var r = new Repository<Departman>();
    }
}
```

The classes are simplified for the purpose of the problem they do much more than shown here. The thing is that Linq to Entities does not allow casting ((IUniqueObject)f).Uid. So how can apply the Tags Filter knowing that generic type T implements IUniqueObject interface. I tried using some GenericMethod with "T2 where : CoreEntity , IUniqueObject" but I could not cast type T to T2, anyways 
any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Return input type of generic with type constraint in LINQ to Entities (EF4.1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175134/return-input-type-of-generic-with-type-constraint-in-linq-to-entities-ef4-1)

Comment: my problem turned out to be same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175134/return-input-type-of-generic-with-type-constraint-in-linq-to-entities-ef4-1?rq=1

Comment: This Works:  query = ((IQueryable<IUniqueObject>)query).Where(f => ts.Any(e => e.TaggedItemUid == f.Uid && tags.Contains(e.TagId))).Cast<T>();

Answer (score 0):

The Where statement in LinqToEntities will be converted to SQL syntax. Every instruction must be translatable into SQL - which means no casting. Still thinking about a more helpful answer. I think you'll need to have distinct functions for the different query types, e.g. add a method like:

```
public IQueryable<T> AddTagsFilterToUniqueObject(IQueryable<T> query, 
                                   List<int> tags) where T : IUniqueObject 
{ 
    var ts = ItemTagSet;

    query = query.Where(f => ts.Any(e => e.TaggedItemUid == (f.Uid && tags.Contains(e.TagId));

    return query;
}
```

Comment: No it does not. think of IUniqueObject interface as saying that this table has an additional Guid field along with the primary key, and use this guid when accessing common tables like documents, notes, tags etc.

Comment: In that case, what class *does* implement IUniqueObject?

Comment: I updated the question adding a sample Departman class implementing the IUniqueObject and deriving from CoreEntity.